# Add text to PowerPoint slide during a presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, annotations

I'd like to add text to selected slides during my presentation. The text is based on audience feedback and is "throw-away", intended just to help with discussion and learning at the moment. The text does not need to integrate with the rest of the slide in any particular way.

I'd like a solution that works for PowerPoint 2010 or later on Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. *One time PowerPoint setup:* Right click the Ribbon and click **Customize the Ribbon**. In the right hand column, put a check box next to **Developer**.
2. *For each slide where you will be adding content:*

   - In the Ribbon, click the **Developer** tab. Click the **Text Box** control; then drag a rectangle for the text box on the slide.
   - Right click the text box, and click **Property Sheet**. Set **EnterKeyBehavior** to True and **MultiLine** to True. If desired, click **Font** and then the “**…**” on the right to change the font and size.

Comment: This does work and it's a clever approach. Readers may be interested to know, however, that the text box won't "flow" like a normal element and may render in unpredictable locations.